# conda info throws version error

Tags: python, version, conda, info

The error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 724, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 75, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 313, in execute
    info_dict = get_info_dict(args.system)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 143, in get_info_dict
    conda_build_version = conda_build.__version__
AttributeError: module 'conda_build' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I'm not sure what's happening, but I suspect it might have something to do with the fact that I cancelled creation of a virtualenv using ctrl-C in the CLI, because I accidentally initiated creation of one and didn't want to wait for it to execute fully. I never activated the environment though, and deleted the few files that had been set up in its folder.

Any ideas on what might be the cause? Conda and all other packages are fully updated (conda v. 4.4.4, which I can see running the conda -V command). So far it is only the info command that throws this error, and I want to use it to check if there are other virtualenvs I need to clean up.

Comment: I would suggest trying to remove conda-build (`conda remove conda-build`) and also "officially" remove the environment you cancelled (`conda env remove -n envname`)

Comment: Apparently I didn't even have conda-build installed, though I have no idea why (not a core package?). Installing it did the trick, though, and thank you for pointing me in the right direction!